# Nginx Ingress "rewrite-target" annotation not rewriting target

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

The "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target" annotation on my ingress resource does not seem to be doing anything. Everything works just fine when I change `path: /helloworld` to `path: /`. I have tried putting the annotation's value in double quotes and changing the order of annotations to no effect. What am I missing? It seems like this should be fairly straightforward.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: helloworld-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <NGINX_CONTROLLER_EXTERNAL_IP>.xip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: helloworld-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /helloworld
```

Comment: So do you reach the back-end service, but the path is still `/helloworld`?

Comment: I have mostly seen the rewrite-target used with regex. I.e. `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` and `path: /helloworld(/|$)(.*)`. This way you would rewrite such that `/helloworld` is removed, but the rest of the of the path is kept. However, if you always want to rewrite to root path, I would think it should work like you've done.. :thinking:

Comment: @ChristianFosli You are right. It should work and it would in most cases. It turns out the problem was related to the service the path was pointing too. It's a Nginx server serving a React.js app. I added an answer with a link to a more detailed post on the issue. Thank you anyway for your efforts.

Comment: No worries :-) Yes, since React.js works on the client side this kind of rewrite won't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem. It was not related to the "rewrite-target" annotation itself. I was trying to point it to a Nginx server serving a React.js app. I needed to set the base URL within the React app and copy the build to the corresponding subdirectory of `/usr/share/nginx/html` in the Dockerfile. After taking those steps there was no need for using "rewrite-target" anymore. I posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546735/rewrite-target-failing-when-routing-to-react-js-app-on-nginx-server/65560923#65560923) detailing the setup with React and Nginx and answered it too.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use app-root if you want to rewrite in the `/` context. https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem was unrelated to the "rewrite-target" annotation. I added an answer with a link to a more detailed post in case someone runs into the same problem.