# "rewrite-target" failing when routing to React.js app on nginx server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a React app which I build and dockerize to be hosted on a nginx server.

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I then create a simple deployment and service for it (which I very much doubt are the problem). Next I create an nginx ingress.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <MY_NGINX_CONTROLLER_EXTERNAL_IP>.xip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-app-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /myapp
```

But when I call `<MY_NGINX_CONTROLLER_EXTERNAL_IP>.xip.io/myapp` I get a 404.

When I change `path: /myapp` to `path: /` I can reach my app with no problems on `<MY_NGINX_CONTROLLER_EXTERNAL_IP>.xip.io`

I have tried numerous variations of `rewrite-target` and `path` like `/$1` and `/myapp/(.*)` but it makes no difference.

I believe the problem lies with using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation to route to a React app. Because using that annotation for any other service on my cluster works just fine.

Others users seem to have similar problems: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3770#. But I was unable to find a solution.

A workaround would be to change the `basename` and `homepage` attributes within my react app and then update all routes. Then I would not need `rewrite-target` at all. But making it work with `rewrite-target` would be much cleaner, especially considering that the path/subdirectory will have to change regularly for my app.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working now. With two additional steps "rewrite-target" annotation is not required at all and can be removed from the ingress resource.

Step 1: Change the base URL within the react app. See how to do this [here](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/).

Step 2: Copy the react build into the corresponding subdirectory of `/usr/share/nginx/html` in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY build /usr/share/nginx/html/myapp
```